# How to strip context path in nginx, zuul and oauth combined

Tags: nginx, oauth, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

I have Nginx proxy with following configuration:

```
upstream gateway_server {
  ip_hash; # sticky session on as there will be more than one destination
  server app.server:8080; 
}

server {

  listen                  0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name             my.domain.net;
  root                    /var/www/gateway;

  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_buffering         off;
  proxy_connect_timeout   5s;
  proxy_read_timeout      120s;
  proxy_next_upstream     error timeout http_502 http_503 http_504;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_intercept_errors  on;

 location / {
   proxy_pass              http://gateway_server/my-application/;
 }

 location /loginPage {
   proxy_pass              http://gateway_server/loginPage;
 }

 location ^~ /login {
   proxy_pass              http://gateway_server/login;
 }

 location /logout {
   proxy_pass              http://gateway_server/logout;
 }

 location /css {
   proxy_pass              http://gateway_server/css;
 }


 error_page 502 503 504 @maintenance;
 location @maintenance {
     rewrite ^(.*)$          /maintenance.html break;
 } 

 error_page 404 /404.html;
 location = /404.html {
   rewrite ^(.*)$          /404.html break;
 }

 error_page 500 /500.html;
 location = /500.html {
   rewrite ^(.*)$          /500.html break;
 }
}
```

The *gateway-server* is pointing at my zuul proxy, which is a simple SpringBoot Application annotated with *@EnableZuulProxy*. Routes are configured as follows:

```
# Zuul configuration
zuul:
  host:
    socket-timeout-millis: 300000 # 5 minutes
  sensitiveHeaders:
  routes:
    my-application:
      path: /my-application/**
      serviceId: my-application
      stripPrefix: false
```

*my-application* is a Spring Boot application combined with angular front-end. Apart from routing, *gateway-server* is also responsible for authentication - it communicates with out OAuth2 multi provider. When a user is not authenticated, and tries to call *my.domain.net* Nginx proxies the call to zuul (*app.server:8080/my-application/*) *gateway-server* starts Oauth2 protocol, and forwards user to a login page, where one can choose his/hers provider (facebook, google, internal). Whole authentication is managed by spring - I don't do any custom things. After successful login user gets redirected to **my.domain.net/my-application** rather than to **my.domain.net**.
Do you have any idea which element in my infrastructure adds this context path? Do you have any idea how could I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use stripPrefix: true because your config:

```
path: /my-application/**
serviceId: my-application
stripPrefix: false
```

tells spring to keep `/my-application/` ( which is 'prefix' in zuul understanding ) after redirect.

Comment: I cannot use stripPrefix = true in here as "/my-application" is the context path in this service (and this is essential as the application uses ajax calls, to get numerous resources, located under this path)